# Row click react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

this component react presents a table with its own row id, what I want to do is to have the possibility to select the row with the mouse-click at the user's click, how can I implement this within this react application? The table loads a series of values ​​from the backend which then displays with reactstrap, how can I fix this?

**React.js Code:**

```
class Static extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.textInput = React.createRef();

    this.state = {
      tableStyles: [
      ],

    };

    this.checkAll = this.checkAll.bind(this);
  }

  parseDate(date) {
    this.dateSet = date.toDateString().split(" ");

    return `${date.toLocaleString("en-us", { month: "long" })} ${
      this.dateSet[2]
    }, ${this.dateSet[3]}`;
  }

  checkAll(ev, checkbox) {
    const checkboxArr = new Array(this.state[checkbox].length).fill(
      ev.target.checked
    );
    this.setState({
      [checkbox]: checkboxArr,
    });
  }

  //Function create user
  async newuser(event){
    let ragionesocialetext = event.target.value;
    console.log("Ragione Sociale: "+ragionesocialetext);
  }

  //Function call con text change
  async handleChange(event) {
    let searchtext = event.target.value;
    var result=await ricercaclienti(searchtext);
    var results=[];
    for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++){
      var value={
        id: result[i].IdCliente,
        picture: require("../../../images/cliente.jpg"), // eslint-disable-line global-require
        description: result[i].RagioneSociale,
        info: {
          citta: result[i].Citta,
          provincia: result[i].Provincia,
        },
        DataInserimento: result[i].DataInserimento,
        Cap: result[i].Cap,
        progress: {
          percent: 30,
          colorClass: "warning",
        }
      };
      results.push(value);
    }
    this.setState({tableStyles: results});
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className={s.root}>
        <h2 className="page-title">
          Clienti - <span className="fw-semi-bold"> Anagrafia</span>
        </h2>
        <Row>
          <Col>

            <Widget

              settings
              close
              bodyClass={s.mainTableWidget}
            >
                <p></p>
                <p></p>
                <p></p>
                <p></p>

            <FormGroup >
            <InputGroup className="input-group-no-border">
              <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                <InputGroupText>
                  <i className="fa fa-search text-white" />
                </InputGroupText>
              </InputGroupAddon>
              <Input
                id="search-input"
                className="input-transparent"
                placeholder="Ricerca"
                type='text'
  name='ricerca'
  onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
              />
            </InputGroup>
          </FormGroup>
              <Table striped>
                <thead>
                  <tr className="fs-sm">
                    <th className="hidden-sm-down">#</th>
                    <th>Cliente</th>
                    <th>Ragione Sociale</th>
                    <th className="hidden-sm-down">Indirizzo</th>
                    <th className="hidden-sm-down">Data Inserimento</th>
                    <th className="hidden-sm-down">CAP</th>
                    <th className="hidden-sm-down">Stato</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {this.state.tableStyles.map((row) => (
                    
                    <tr key={row.id}>
                      <td>{row.id}</td>
                      <td>
                        <img
                          className="img-rounded"
                          src={row.picture}
                          alt=""
                          height="50"
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        {row.description}
                        {row.label && (
                          <div>
                            <Badge color={row.label.colorClass}>
                              {row.label.text}
                            </Badge>
                          </div>
                        )}
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <p className="mb-0">
                          <small>
                            Città:
                            <span className="text-muted fw-semi-bold">
                              &nbsp; {row.info.citta}
                            </span>
                          </small>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                          <small>
                            Provincia:
                            <span className="text-muted fw-semi-bold">
                              &nbsp; {row.info.provincia}
                            </span>
                          </small>
                        </p>
                      </td>
                      <td className="text-muted">{row.DataInserimento}</td>
                      <td className="text-muted">{row.Cap}</td>
                      <td className="width-150">
                        <Progress
                          color={row.progress.colorClass}
                          value={row.progress.percent+row.i}
                          className="progress-sm mb-xs"
                        />
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  ))}
                </tbody>
              </Table>
              <div className="clearfix">
                <div className="float-right">
                  <Button color="default" className="mr-2" size="sm">
                    Refresh...
                  </Button>
                  <UncontrolledButtonDropdown>
                    <DropdownToggle
                      color="inverse"
                      className="mr-xs"
                      size="sm"
                      caret
                    >
                      Nuovo Cliente
                    </DropdownToggle>
                    <DropdownMenu>
                      <DropdownItem>Inserisci ragione sociale</DropdownItem>
                      <Input
                id="search-input"
                className="input-transparent"
                placeholder="ragionesociale"
                type='text'
  name='ragionesociale'
  onChange={this.newuser.bind(this)}
              />

                    </DropdownMenu>
                  </UncontrolledButtonDropdown>
                </div>
                <p></p>
              </div>
            </Widget>
          </Col>
        </Row>

                          </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can bind the click event on the `<tr>` and add `data-attributes` on `<tr>` for getting the rowId user clicked on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set a `selectedRowId` variable in your state, then add

```
onClick={() => {this.setState({ selectedRowId: row.id })}}
```

prop to wherever the user should click to select the row. If you want to change the styles of the row based on if it is selected or not, you can change the class of the row element by adding

```
className={this.state.selectedRowId===row.id?'selected':'unselected'}
```

then adding styles for a selected and unselected class.